# Trouble updating json files

Tags: python, json

I have two `json` files. One of them is a dictionary which is a subset of the other.

`json_file_1.json` contains `{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3}`

`json_file_2.json` contains `{'foo': 100, 'bar': 200}`.

I want to create a final `json` file that has the following: `{'foo': 100, 'bar': 200, 'baz': 3}`

Here is what I tried so far:

```
with open('json_file_1.json') as f1:
    original_info = json.load(f1)
f1.close()

with open('json_file_2.json') as f2:
    updated_info = json.load(f2)
f2.close()

print original_info  # prints the correct dictionary
print updated_info   # prints the correct dictionary

final_info = original_info.update(updated_info)

print final_info  # prints None

with open('json_file_final.json', 'w+') as f_final:
    json.dump(final_info, f_final)
```

However, when I open the final `json` file, it only contains "Null". When I tried debugging it, I printed out `original_info` and `updated_info`, and they were each fine. I could call `original_info.update(updated_info)` and that would produce a dictionary that was properly updated. However, it just isn't working for some reason when it's all put together?

Any thoughts?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You don't need to close a file if using `with`

Comment: @cricket_007 cool, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=update#dict.update) updates a dictionary in-place and returns `None`.

You need to dump `original_info`

For reference,

```
In [11]: d1 = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3}

In [12]: d2 = {'foo': 100, 'bar': 200}

In [13]: d3 = d1.update(d2)

In [14]: d3

In [15]: print(d3)
None

In [16]: d1
Out[16]: {'bar': 200, 'baz': 3, 'foo': 100}
```

Comment: Welcome. I have added the link to the documentation as well, which says as much